# Android Manifest:Same meta-data tag with multiple values

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I have a basic question about the syntax for the Android Manifest. Basically I have the same key two times and I want it to store two values.

```xml
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
```

Unfortunately, the above example won't work. The lower example doesn't work either.

```xml
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode,ocr" />
```

So what's the correct way to map "barcode" and "ocr" to the key?
Thanks

Comment: In the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/multi-tracker-tutorial#querying_the_detector_operational_status) the second way is used, probably it is fine. Do you check if detector is operational as it is proposed in the docs: `if (!detector.isOperational()) {
    // ...
}`?

Comment: Strange. It seems to be a bug only related to Huawei then. Thank you.