# Manifest cannot resolve add tools:replace="android:value" to <meta-data> element

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, android-manifest, manifest

I am working on project in which I have used two sdks one is **Persona SDK**  and second
**Ramp SDK**. after adding Ramp sdk dependency it started giving me this error.

[Here is error while building project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeDwM.png)

and after adding **tools:replace="android:value"** to my manifest here..

[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9dRK.png)

it started to give me this error.
**tools:replace specified at line:12 for attribute android:value, but no new value specified**
check here

[Manifest merge failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygD5X.png)

I tried put metadata as well but the **value(face)** in both of sdks is creating issue how can
resolve this please help here.
I tried everything possible but I couldn't figured it out. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The Android Studio suggestion is not helpful, I don't recommend adding `android:value` to your `replace`. How are you defining these two `value` metadatas, is it similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59826331/608312)?

Comment: @JakeLee yes, i was adding same as you mentioned. but it didn't work, also it I tried adding same value (face) in metadata in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding these in **Manifest**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
```